# changing text with different duration in javascript

Tags: javascript, text, animatewithduration

Hello stackoverflow community,

my goal is to create changing text with different duration, meaning that there are certain "markers" or sentences which stay longer then the 2 seconds I have now as of now. 
Also, I would like the animation to stop after all the list entries have been displayed.

Here is the code I have for now:

http://jsfiddle.net/eu8L01nv/

Javacript:

```
    var terms = $("ul li");

    function rotateTerm() {

     var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;

     console.log(terms.eq([ct]).text());

      $("#rotate").data("term", 
        ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms.eq([ct]).text())
      .fadeIn().delay(2000).fadeOut(200, rotateTerm);

    }
    $(rotateTerm);
```

HTML

```
    <p><span id="rotate">default</span></p>

    <ul style="display:none">
        <li>This is sentence number one.</li>
        <li>That is sentence number two.</li>
        <li>This is another sentence.</li>
        <li>Another sentence.</li>
    </ul>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this solves the issue:

I added this piece of code to it: `ct < terms.length -1 && rotateTerm`. so that it won't call `rotateTerm` function after the last element

And I have added a timeDelay array `var timeDelay = [1000, 2000, 4000, 8000]` to enable different time delays for different sentences.

```
var terms = $("ul li");

    function rotateTerm() {

     var timeDelay = [1000, 2000, 4000, 8000];
     var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
     console.log(terms.eq([ct]).text());
     console.log(ct)
      $("#rotate").data("term", 
        ct == terms.length -1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(terms.eq([ct]).text())
      .fadeIn().delay(timeDelay[ct]).fadeOut(200, ct < terms.length -1 && rotateTerm);

    }
    $(rotateTerm);
```

Or you could set the delay depending upon the length of the text

```
var terms = $("ul li");

function rotateTerm() {

  var ct = $("#rotate").data("term") || 0;
  const text = terms.eq([ct]).text()
  const textLength = text.length;
  console.log(textLength)
  const timeDelay = textLength < 50 ? 2000 : textLength * 50
  $("#rotate").data("term",
      ct == terms.length - 1 ? 0 : ct + 1).text(text)
    .fadeIn().delay(timeDelay).fadeOut(200, ct < terms.length - 1 && rotateTerm);

}
$(rotateTerm);
```

Comment: Thank you, that helps me already a lot! Do you also know if there is any way to display some sentences longer, maybe be creating some unique list elements?

Comment: yes. I have updated the answer as per your requirement. Hope it helps